# Can the Linux console display 16 colors?

Tags: linux, colors, console

I'm reading the manual page `terminfo` and I wonder if the Linux console may 
use the terminal type `linux-16color` instead of the terminal type `linux`.

```
prompt% infocmp linux linux-16color
comparing linux to linux-16color.
comparing booleans.
comparing numbers.
colors: 8, 16.
ncv: 18, 42.
pairs: 64, 256.
comparing strings.
setab: '\E[4%p1%dm', '\E[4%p1%{8}%m%d%?%p1%{7}%>%t;5%e;25%;m'.
setaf: '\E[3%p1%dm', '\E[3%p1%{8}%m%d%?%p1%{7}%>%t;1%e;21%;m'.
```

I replaced the terminal type`linux` in `/etc/inittab` by `linux-16color` but the Linux console seems to display only eight colors. I thought the terminal type `linux-16color` could be specified to display sixteen colors, concerning the Linux console. I have also tried to set the environment variable `TERM` to `linux-16color` without success.

Can the Linux console display sixteen colors? Can the Linux console support the terminal type `linux-16color`?

### See Also

- [Terminal code (ANSI/VT100)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes#additional_colors)

Comment: just trying, there's something strange with regard to \e[30m and \e[90m (when using ainsi codes). If you start a loop with 31..37 vs 91..97 (avoiding 30 and 90) you should see more than 8 colors. I have no idea what's the meaning

Answer (score 3):

The `linux-16color` terminal description uses the [console](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)'s blink- and bold-attributes to map codes 0-15 into the 16 colors that the console is capable of doing.  In the description, that is done using the **`5`** vs **`25`** and **`1`** vs **`21`** constants in the **`setaf`** and **`setab`** capabilities which you may notice in the console_codes(4) manual page.

You might find it easier to see using the **`-f`** option of `infocmp`:

```
    setab=\E[4 
            %p1%{8}%m%d 
            %? 
                    %p1%{7}%> 
                    %t;5 
            %e 
                    ;25 
            %; 
            m,
```

The sequence (reading top to bottom) does this:

- sends an ASCII escape (the `\E`) followed by `[` and `4`
- checks if the first parameter is greater than 7

  - if yes, sends `;` (a delimiter) and `5` (the **`blink`** attribute)
  - if no, sends `;` `2` `5` to turn **`blink`** off)
- finishes the SGR by sending `m`

Those attributes happen to work with VGA drivers which don't (generally) cause the text to blink, or use a different font to show bold text.  Instead, they allow extending the set of colors (in a nonstandard manner, of course).  If you have a different display device (such as the virtual machines I work with), none of that applies anymore.

There's a complication since that was set up: configurations which load a Unicode-capable font (i.e., 512 glyphs versus the original 256) take over one of the bits used for those 16 colors, so you really only get 8 colors.  That's mentioned here and there [this for example](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.1/chapter07/console.html), but was introduced since the manual page was last updated:

> Due to the use of a 512-glyph LatArCyrHeb-16 font in the previous example, bright colors are no longer available on the Linux console unless a framebuffer is used. If one wants to have bright colors without framebuffer and can live without characters not belonging to his language, it is still possible to use a language-specific 256-glyph font, as illustrated below: